# Nav Bar collapse not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the nav bar help the navbar don't open when in mobile mode please help me
The navbar shows the drop down button but nothing happens in mobile mode please help

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Theatre</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?> 

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="navbar-right"><a href="./logout.php" class="btn btn-danger" style="color:whitesmoke;">logout</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li <?= echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("index") ?>>
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li <?= echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("productions") ?>>
                        <a href="productions.php">Productions</a></li>    
                </ul>

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>


                <?php
            } else {
                ?>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="index.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name ="email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                    <a href="./register.php" class="btn btn-warning">Register</a>
                </form>
            <?php }
            ?> 
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should take time to use better syntax, better format, give more info and/or code.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
 one <ul> and many <li> for your navigation (not many <ul> and <li>
```

Comment: hoow do i set thingss to the right ofd the nav bar without 2 <ul>

Comment: li {
    display: inline;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding a simple on click function to your button

```
function navbarshow(){ 
    var x = document.getElementById('collapse-navbar');
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
 }
```

and call the function in your button
`onclick="navbarshow()"`.